# Error while writing opencv frames to HLS segment file

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, gstreamer

I am processing hls video segment through opencv. My intention is to create another segment file with processed frames. After some research I found it could be achieved using gstreamer pipeline. I followed the sample but it didn't work for me

**Code Sample**

```
   vs = cv2.VideoCapture(video)
   fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"MJPG")
   writer = cv2.VideoWriter("appsrc num-buffers=100 ! x264enc ! queue ! mpegtsmux name=mux ! filesink location="+outpath, fourcc, 30, (W, H), True)
   while True:
       frame = vs.read()
       frame = frame[1]
       frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
       rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
       writer.write(frame)
```

**Error**

```
OpenCV: FFMPEG: tag 0x47504a4d/'MJPG' is not supported with codec id 7 and format 'mpegts / MPEG-TS (MPEG-2 Transport Stream)'
[ERROR:0] global /private/var/folders/nz/vv4_9tw56nv9k3tkvyszvwg80000gn/T/pip-req-build-gi6lxw0x/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp (563) open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.4.0) /private/var/folders/nz/vv4_9tw56nv9k3tkvyszvwg80000gn/T/pip-req-build-gi6lxw0x/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_images.cpp:267: error: (-215:Assertion failed) number < max_number in function 'icvExtractPattern'
```

I tried different possible combinations of codecs('MJPG','MPV4','MPEG' etc..) but so far no luck :(. Any help/suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I also tried "mpegts" and "MPEG-TS" but in that case I get below error. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "processor.py", line 201, in <module>
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mpegts")
TypeError: VideoWriter_fourcc() takes at most 4 arguments (6 given)

Answer (score 2):

For `x264enc` you need to define `fourcc` either:

- If you have `x264` is installed

  ```
  fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'x264')
  ```

  or

  ```
  fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
  ```

In my case `mp4v` has worked

```
import cv2

vs = cv2.VideoCapture("video.mp4")

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')

W = int(vs.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
H = int(vs.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

writer = cv2.VideoWriter("result.mp4", fourcc, 30.0, (W, H), True)

while True:
    ret, frame = vs.read()
    if ret:
        writer.write(frame)
    else:
        break

vs.release()
writer.release()
```

Comment: mp4v works! Is MPEG-TS the same as mp4? can I use .mp4 in HLS streaming?

Comment: Glad, if I could help :), Well, the MPEG Transport Stream may work the same as `.mp4`. If it doesn't you could  `MJPG` instead of `mp4v` and `.avi` instead of `.mp4`

Comment: I tried but mp4 doesn't work in streaming. Any other way to convert to MPEG-TS